# Nokogiri returning values as a string, not an array

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm running a script using Nokogiri that returns multiple values. I was under the impression (and reassured by multiple sources) that the results should be in the form of an array. Instead I'm getting an ugly looking string. Here is the code

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'spreadsheet'

profile_page_scraper = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.crunchbase.com/company/facebook'))       
puts profile_page_scraper.css('div.col1_content td.td_left').text
```

Which returns this:

```
PublicDateRaisedPost IPO ValuationWebsiteBlogTwitterCategoryEmployeesFoundedDescription
```

I know I can use `map` to fix this quickly, but I am confused as to why this isn't returning an array. It should, theoretically, return something like this:

```
["Public", "Date", "Raised" ... "Description"]
```

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: You should accept one of the answers below.

Answer (score 7):

`NodeSet#text` always returns a string (otherwise it would probably be called `NodeSet#texts`). Nokogiri docs are not so great, when in doubt check the source code:

```
  # lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb
  def inner_text
    collect{|j| j.inner_text}.join('')
  end
  alias :text :inner_text
```

To get an array of texts: `nodes.map(&:text)`

Comment: Nokogiri's [`Node.text` documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri%2FXML%2FNode%3Acontent) says "Returns the content for this Node" whereas the [`Nodeset.text` documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri%2FXML%2FNodeSet%3Ainner_text) says "Get the inner text of all contained Node objects". The second concatenates the text from all nodes contained in the NodeSet into a single string.

Answer (score 1):

The `css` method is returning an instance of `Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet`, which includes `Enumerable`.

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.crunchbase.com/company/facebook'))  
nodes = doc.css('div.col1_content td.td_left')
nodes.class.ancestors
# => [Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet, Enumerable, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

So you can use all the standard iterators in conjunction with the `content` attribute of each element in this result set. For example:

```
nodes.each { |n| puts n.content }
```